# Onsen UI: Get content height

Tags: onsen-ui

I have tried everything but can't seem to get the height of the page content. I am using Onsen UI with JQuery. Can anyone provide me with an example?

I am trying to calculate the height minus the navbar so that I can adjust a map to full height.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to calculate any height, just put the map in a div and set the style to something like that:

```css
#map_canvas {
    position: absolute; 
    width:100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;   
    z-index: -1
}
```

Anyway, if you really need the height of the current page, you can get it with JQuery using `$('.page__content').height();`

Comment: Thanks @Andi Pavllo! I had to include the page id as follows in order to get it to work: $("#page-detail .page__content").height();

Comment: p.s. @MoreScratch if you are interested, I just posted an article on Onsen UI blog about how to integrate Google Maps with Onsen UI, assuming it's the kind of map you were interested to implement.

http://onsen.io/blog/onsen-ui-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-angularjs-sample-application/